# PayPal Payments Pro: Way to charge One-time fee when modifying a recurring profile?

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

From a business perspective: Clients may have a subscription for $29 a month. Now they want the next tier ($59/month). They change tiers mid-month. Now, not only do I want to modify their existing profile to $59/month, but I would like to charge a one-time fee of $15 (Assuming the user made the change mid-month, $15 is my prorated amount).

Is there any way to do this with PayPal Payments Pro (Previously "Website Payments Pro")?

I have already tried:

OPTIONALTRX
-Only valid for PayPal Payflow Pro

TRIALAMT
-Only useful if I had used it when creating the initial recurring profile. Even if I did, I don't think I am allowed to make the amount higher

Thanks in advance,
Mike